# How to convert visual foxpro 6 report to word

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have used following code to show a report.

```
select mem_no,com_name,owner,owner_cate,iif(empty(photo),"c:\edrs\memphoto\void.JPG",iif(file(photo),photo,"c:\edrs\memphoto\void.JPG")) as photo from own1  into curs own

REPO FORM c:\edrs\reports\rptsearch.frx TO PRINT PREVIEW NOCONS
```

Here rptsearch.frx contains some image. The following code export data to excel except image.

```
COPY TO "c:\documents and settings\administrator\desktop\a.xls" TYPE XLS
```

In case of image it shows only the path name. Now I need to know how I can convert this report in word so that I can have the images in the word report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that you are creating a simple list with pictures. One of the easiest ways to do that is to use automation. ie:

```
Select mem_no,com_name,owner,owner_cate,;
    iif(Empty(photo) Or !File(photo),"c:\edrs\memphoto\void.JPG",photo) As photo ;
    from own1  ;
    into Curs crsData ;
    nofilter

#Define wdWord9TableBehavior 1
#Define wdAutoFitWindow 2
#Define wdStory 6
#Define wdCollapseEnd 0
#Define wdCellAlignVerticalCenter 1
#Define CR Chr(13)

Local Array laCaptions[5]
laCaptions[1] = 'Mem No'
laCaptions[2] = 'Com Name'
laCaptions[3] = 'Owner'
laCaptions[4] = 'Owner Cate'
laCaptions[5] = 'Photo'

Local nRows, nCols, ix
nRows = Reccount('crsData')+1
nCols = Fcount('crsData')+1

oWord = Createobject('Word.Application')
With m.oWord
    oDocument = .Documents.Add
    With m.oDocument.Tables.Add( m.oWord.Selection.Range, m.nRows, m.nCols)
        .BorderS.InsideLineStyle = .F.
        .BorderS.OutsideLineStyle = .F.

        For ix=1 To Alen(laCaptions)
            **** Add captions *****
            .Cell(1,m.ix).Range.InsertAfter( laCaptions[m.ix] )
        Endfor

        Select crsData
        Scan
            For ix=1 To Fcount()-1 && last one is photo path
                **** Add values to the different cells *****
                .Cell(Recno()+1,m.ix).Range.InsertAfter( Eval(Field(m.ix)) )
            Endfor
            lcPhoto = crsData.photo
            If File(m.lcPhoto) && Add photo if any
                oDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture( m.lcPhoto, .T., .T.,;
                    .Cell(Recno()+1,Fcount()).Range)
            Endif
            .Rows(Recno()+1).Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalCenter
        Endscan
    Endwith

    .Visible = .T.
Endwith
```

However, sending data to word this way would suffer from performance if you have many rows. You can use this for small data like an employee table or so. With larger data, instead of using automation, you could simply create an HTML document and word would open an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do it. I would investigate [FoxyPreviewer](https://foxypreviewer.codeplex.com/) and use that to report to RTF, which Word can open.

Or do it the other way round with a mail merge in Word.

Comment: I have downloaded the FoxyPreviewer. I am confused about some points: 1. where to keep this file and how to use it? 2. In this link 'https://foxypreviewer.codeplex.com/documentation'  what is meant by 'beginning of your executable' and 'YourReport'. should I write like this 'report form "c:\edrs\reports\rptsearch.frx" To PRINT object type 12 NOCONS' for my example and 'DO FOXYPREVIEWER.APP' at the beginning of that button click

Answer (score 0):

In addition to FoxyPreviewer, you could also use OLE Office automation to programmatically build the report. There are numerous examples online, and even a book, Microsoft Office Automation, written by Tamar E. Granor & Della Martin.

I have not done a lot with automation, only enough to get it basically verify it works, and discover it was very slow for what I was attempting to do.